# Change textbox value programatically on Visual Studio Setup project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I'm developing a Setup project using Visual Stual Studio 2008 using language C#.
I added a Dialog with 4 textboxes to allow the users to provide some needed information.
Is there any way to fill the value of one of the textboxes programatically, and the user only validate is it's correct and changes it if necessary.

Comment: Visual Studio... in what language? C? C++? VB.NET? C#? Etc.

Comment: C#, sorry forgot to specify the language.

Answer (score 1):

Open the properties page on the dialog and change Edit1Value, Edit2Value, Edit3Value, or Edit4Value from nothing to something.

Comment: That actually does the trick, but what I need is to set Edit1Value programatically with C#

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to add any code to a VS Setup Project.

Answer (score 0):

```
textboxname.Text = "whateveryouwant";
```

This?

Comment: No. The problem is to do that in a Textbox inside a Interface Dialog in a Visual Studio Setup project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an installer class for coding for installation (see [this link](http://msforge.net/blogs/notequ/archive/2008/03/14/installer-class.aspx)). However, I don't know how to dynamically set the text box's value.